Objects that are sharing same code are interfering each other?
I have two object on my scene, that are sharing same code. When I am instantiating those on my scene, I am assigning them a unique ID in _ready func:
func _ready():
    
    # Setting values. 
    houseid = randi() % 50

I also have a function that creates an interface whenever I am clicking on a building:
func _on_building_static_input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    click += 1
    if event.is_pressed() and click > 1:
        var func_button = interfacePanel.get_child(4)
        func_button.set_text("Cut" + ' ' + str(houseid))
        func_button.visible = true
        func_button.pressed.connect(self.CutArea)

So I am creating an interface button (it works okay) and connecting it to a function that makes a simple print:
func CutArea():
    print('Test works from building ', houseid) 

This function indeed prints a text, but if I have 2 or more buildings, all the IDs of those buildings and same amount of line (like if I have 2 buildings > I have 2 lines of output) output.
I clearly can see that interface is different, here are examples:


So I expected that if I will click 'Cut 3' I will have an output of 'Test works from building 3' but instead I am getting this:

I assume that something is wrong with way of connection button to a script, but can't figure out the correct way. Godot 4.2!
Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Solution: create a new button (with Button.new()) each time when interface is instantiated, store the button in array. And then delete all buttons from array each time when interface is instantiated.
